# Pde system problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have a big problem to solve this system
$\Delta f-hf^2=0$

$|\nabla f|^2+hf^3=0$

where $h$ is a constant, $f$ is a 2-dimensional smooth function, $\Delta f$ is Laplacian of $f$ (i.e. $\Delta f=f_{xx}+f_{yy}$) and $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$.

ADD
In first case $f$ is defined on $R^2$
and in second case $f$ is defined on surface $S$ ($f:S \rightarrow (0, \infty)$).
is there a solution?
Thank you for help

MODIFICATION after Igor Khavkine answer:
and if the system is

$\Delta f-hf^2+cf=0$

$|\nabla f|^2+hf^3=0$

(c is another constant)

Comment: Please give some context as to why you are interested in this problem.

Comment: @Chris Ramsey, I found a particular manifold with Einstein condition in isotropic space... $f$ is defined on surface and it is a positive scalar function

Comment: I don't understand your question, you have a system of two PDEs about a scalar function $f$ (which means surely your system is overdetermined). But then you say that simultaneously $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a surface $S$: which is it?

Comment: @Willie Wong, No, are two separate case.. I said that badly, sorry!

Comment: If you have two different questions, why not ask them separately? It will be easier to understand the questions and the answers if you ask the questions separately.

Comment: @exxxit8, I strongly encourage you to first work through the steps of the $h=c=0$ and $c=0,h\ne 0$ cases, and then apply the same method to the $c\ne 0$ case.

Comment: @exxxit8, for exemple $h=c=0$ implies $f$ harmonic, and the result is the same for $h \neq 0$ and $c=0$, i.e. $h \neq 0$ and $f=0$, or $h=0$ and $f=$constant.

Comment: @Alexander Pigazzini, thank you very much

Comment: @Igor Khavkine, thank you very much, but I don't understand for $c$ not zero.

Comment: @exxxit8, all these different cases are quite similar. So if you don't understand the $c\ne 0$ case, I'm sorry to say, then you probably don't understand the other cases either. What you should do first is thoroughly understand the cases where the solution is known.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume that, in the surface case, the OP wants to interpret $S$ as a surface endowed with a Riemannian metric and wants to understand the solutions to the equations $\Delta f - hf^2 = 0$ and $|\nabla f|^2 + hf^3 = 0$ for a given constant $h$.

Clearly, if $h=0$, the only solutions are to have $f$ be constant, so one can assume that $h\not=0$.  Then, setting $u = -hf$, the above equations are equivalent to $\Delta u + u^2 = 0$ and $|\nabla u|^2 - u^3 = 0$, so it suffices to solve these latter equations.

Let $g$ be the metric on $S$ and assume that $u$ is a nonzero (and, hence, necessarily positive) solution to the above equations on a simply-connected open subset $S'\subset S$. The second equation implies that $\omega_1 = u^{-3/2}\,\mathrm{d}u$ is a $1$-form with $g$-norm $1$ on $S'$, and hence $g$ can be written in the form $g = {\omega_1}^2 + {\omega_2}^2$ on $S'$ for some $\omega_2$, which is also a unit 1-form.

Fix an orientation by requiring that $\omega_1\wedge\omega_2$ be the $g$-area form on $S'$.  Then $\star \mathrm{d}u = u^{3/2}\,\omega_2$, and since $\mathrm{d}(\star \mathrm{d}u) = \Delta u\, \omega_1\wedge\omega_2$, it follows that
$$
\tfrac32\,u^{1/2}\mathrm{d}u\wedge\omega_2 + u^{3/2}\,\mathrm{d}\omega_2
=\mathrm{d}(u^{3/2}\,\omega_2) = -u^2\,\omega_1\wedge\omega_2 = -u^{1/2}\,\mathrm{d}u\wedge\omega_2\,,
$$
or
$$
\mathrm{d}\omega_2 = -\tfrac52\,u^{-1}\,\mathrm{d}u\wedge\omega_2\,,
$$
which can be written in the form 
$$
\mathrm{d}\bigl(u^{5/2}\,\omega_2\bigr) = 0.
$$
Since $S'$ is simply connected, it follows that there exists a function $v$ on $S'$ such that $u^{5/2}\,\omega_2 = \mathrm{d}v$.  Consequently, the metric $g$ has the form
$$
g = {\omega_1}^2 + {\omega_2}^2 = u^{-3}\,\mathrm{d}u^2 + u^{-5}\,\mathrm{d}v^2.
$$
This metric can be placed in 'polar form' by setting $u = 4r^{-2}$ and $v = 32\theta$, in which case, it becomes
$$
g = \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^{10}\,\mathrm{d}\theta^2,
$$
This is a singular, incomplete metric at $r=0$ (where $u$ goes to $\infty$), though it is complete at $r=\infty$.  Its Gauss curvature is $K = -(r^5)''/r^5 = -20 r^{-2} = -5u < 0$.

The original $f$ then takes the form $f = -u/h = -4/(hr^2)$.

Thus, up to isometry, there is essentially only one solution to the OP's original problem.  (In particular, as Igor showed in his answer, there is no nonconstant solution when the background metric $g$ is flat.)  The modified problem (with the additional constant $c$) can be solved using essentially the same techniques.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, then if I understand for the case with $c$ not zero, the answer is the same, i.e. $f$ constant and $h=c=0$ ?

Comment: you say there is only one solution (ie $ f $ constant and $ h = 0 $) because if $ h $ is not zero, $ f $ is a not smooth function..is this so? instead in the case of Igor Khavkine (which is the case where the metric is flat) the solution for $h$ not zero is $f=0$.

Comment: @exxxit8:  You have not read my analysis carefully.  I showed that, when $h$ is nonzero, then, *on the open set where $f$ is nonzero*, it has a particular form (as described above).  Obviously, $f=0$ is a solution, but that can be discarded as trivial.

Comment: you are right! I read fast. And for $c$ not zero, Do you expect something like that?

Comment: @exxxit8:  Yes.  The analysis is essentially the same:  Set $u=-hf$, and the first equation becomes $\Delta u + u^2 + cu = 0$.  On the open set where $u\not=0$, it is positive, so set $u = 4/r^2$, and we find that $\omega_1 = \mathrm{d}r$ and $\omega_2 = r^5\mathrm{e}^{(c/4)r^2}\mathrm{d}\theta$ for some angular coordinate $\theta$.  The metric $$g=\mathrm{d}r^2 +r^{10}\mathrm{e}^{(c/2)r^2}\mathrm{d}\theta ^2$$ is therefore not flat, so there are no nontrivial solutions on the flat plane, but there is a nontrivial solution $f = -4/(hr^2)$ with $g$ as background metric.

Comment: @Robert Bryant, sorry if I intrude in the discussion, but the last solution ($c \neq 0$) is valid for surfaces with boundary ($\partial S \neq0$) or is the same also for surfaces without boundary ($\partial S=0$)?

Comment: @AlexanderPigazzini:  I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.  A non-zero solution $u$ cannot go to zero in finite distance, even if $c$ is not zero.  The solution as I've described it would be valid on any simply-connected domain on which $u$ is nonzero, so I'm not sure what the boundary, if one exists, would have to do with anything (assuming that the metric and solution are sufficiently differentiable on the boundary).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Robert Bryant, it is exactly this, I did not think that we are in a simply-connected domain where $u$ is nonzero, then there isn't reason  to ask if there is a boundary...thank you very much!

Comment: @RobertBryant,  the solution with $c \neq 0$ is not singular, I am right?

Comment: @exxxit8:  It is not singular except at $r=0$, but then the metric is singular there, so you could certainly say that the solution is not singular on a smooth surface.

Comment: @RobertBryant, then is the same for $c=0$, in both cases ($c=0$ and $c \neq 0$ ) the metric is singular in $r=0$, but if I consider only smooth surfaces, the metrics (in both cases) are not singular because $r=0$ will be not contained in the surfaces..is it right?

Comment: @exxxit8:  Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @RobertBryant, then is enough to say that the surface is smooth for consider both metrics not singular.Thank you for your help

Comment: @RobertBryant, and these are the only nontrivial metrics (for $c=0$ and $\neq 0$), that the surface can admits, is it right?

Comment: @exxxit8:  Yes, up to isometry.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that your system is simply defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I don't know what you mean for this system to be defined on a surface $S$, since you haven't told us anything about $S$. Note that your equations are in the form $E_2 := f_{xx} + f_{yy} -hf^2 = 0$ and $E_1 := f_x^2+f_y^2 + hf^3=0$. I will assume also that $h$ is a non-zero constant.

If you differentiate $E_2$ you can algebraically solve $(E_2,(E_1)_x, (E_1)_y) = 0$ for the highest derivatives and get
\begin{align*}
F_1 &:= f_{xy} - 4 f_x f_y/f = 0, \\
F_2 &:= f_{xx} + 4 f_y^2/f + 3hf^2/2 = 0, \\
F_3 &:= f_{yy} + 4 f_x^2/f + 3hf^2/2 = 0.
\end{align*}

If you cross-differentiate the $F$-equations you can algebraically eliminate all second derivatives from $((F_1)_x - (F_2)_y, (F_1)_y - (F_3)_x) = 0$ and end up with two first order equations. Using $E_1$ to simplify them, unless I made some calculation mistake, the result is equivalent to $f_x = 0$ and $f_y = 0$. Finally, eliminating all derivatives from $E_1$, we end up with the condition $f=0$. Thus $f(x,y) \equiv 0$ is the only solution to your system of equations.

If $h=0$, then after the first step, you end up with the equations
\begin{align*}
F_1 &:= f_{xy} = 0, \\
F_2 &:= f_{xx} = 0, \\
F_3 &:= f_{yy} = 0.
\end{align*}
The only solutions are $f(x,y) = Ax+By+C$ with constants $A$, $B$, $C$. Equation $E_1=0$ forces the constraint $A^2+B^2=0$. So, if you only want positive solutions, the only possibility is $f(x,y) \equiv C$, for some positive constant $C>0$.